# How to add ^B (ASCII code - 2) in String in scala

Tags: scala, ascii

I have a string abc,def . I need to convert all the ',' into "^B" (ASCII code 2) . How can we do it in scala.

i tried

```
var l = str.replace(',', 2.asInstanceOf[Char])
var l = str.replace(',', 2.tochar)
```

but both are not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STX has code 2 in both ascii and UTF-16:

```
"abc,def".replace(',', '\u0002')
```

Comment: @Alok how so? It replaces the , with STX when I evaluate it in my repl.

Comment: This works for me also. `"abc,def".replace(',', '\u0002').getBytes()(3)` evaluates to `2`

Comment: The variant with `2.toChar` from OPs question works as well.

Comment: This is how i tried .. 
scala> val str = "abc,def".replace(',', '\u0002')
str: String = abc?def




scala> print(str)
abcdef
scala>

Comment: Yes .. i got it too.. There was issue with my editor . its working now .. thanks